# PayPal charged, but payment response is "INVALID"

Tags: paypal, response, paypal-ipn, payment, invalidation

several of the webshops from our customers provide a checkout via PayPal.
Actually we have the problem, that when we're forcing a checkout, we get the answer, that something went wrong. But if we check the PayPal Account, then we see, that the charging still has taken place.
Now we're looking for the reason and figured out following:
- If we use a PayPal Sandbox Account, it all works fine
- The payment status is "Completed" (in both cases)
- www.sandbox.paypal.com returns "VERIFIED"
- www.paypal.com returns "INVALID"

Can anyone help us out in this case?

I'll attach two files with the responses from your servers.

Webshop-Request-Parameters:

cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=0.01&invoice=zz_zzzzzzzz&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&item_number1=zzzzzzzz&payer_id=CCCCCCCCCCCCC&tax=0.00&payment_date=05%3A10%3A46+Apr+29%2C+2015+PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=UTF-8&mc_shipping=0.00&mc_handling=0.00&first_name=JOHN&mc_fee=0.01&notify_version=3.8&custom=2&payer_status=verified&business=john%40doe.com&num_cart_items=1&mc_handling1=0.00&payer_email=john%40aol.com&verify_sign=GiPC9Bj...&mc_shipping1=0.00&tax1=0.00&txn_id=CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC&payment_type=instant&last_name=Doe&item_name1=00000000&receiver_email=john%40doe.com&payment_fee=0.01&quantity1=1&receiver_id=CCCCCCCCCCCCC&txn_type=cart&mc_gross_1=0.01&mc_currency=USD&residence_country=US&transaction_subject=2&payment_gross=0.01&auth=AHMdYo7nB...

... = hash algorithm

Response is the standard PayPal-Header plus an "INVALID"

Some Support-Responses from the PayPal support team:

1.You need to include your PayerID as User-Agent in the HTTP Header
2.Use the URL https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr for the post-back to bypass the AKAMAI.

Both solutions were unsuccessful

Next PayPal support solutions

•Check that your are posting your response to the correct URL, which is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr (for Sandbox IPNs) or https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr (for live IPNs). You will receive INVALID if you are testing in the Sandbox and your listener posts back to the live site (and vice versa).

•Verify that your response to the test IPN message contains exactly the same variables and values as the test message and that they are in the same order as in the test message. Finally, verify that the original variables are preceded by a cmd=_notify-validate variable.

•Verify that your response to an IPN: ◦contains exactly the same variables and values as the original IPN.
◦places these variables and values in the same order as does the original IPN.
◦precedes these variables with a cmd=_notify-validate variable.

•Ensure that you use the same character encoding for your response string as the encoding specified in the charset field of the original IPN message. When testing using the IPN Simulator, the character encoding will always be UTF-8.

... were unsuccessful, too

Comment: Can you paste a transaction id for which you received invalid response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was figured out by wrong Charset set on the account settings.
In the "My Account" settings (under "More Encoding Options") the Econding has to be set for what your application sends. (In our case it had to be changed from paypal account installation default to UTF-8)

Comment: Path to the setting:

**Profil -> My selling tools-> PayPal button language encoding -> More Options** 

The default encoding will be set when you sign up for a PayPal account. The system determines your default language and encoding based on your country of origin.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/ProfileAndTools/#id08A9F0660UU

Answer (score 1):

Update on the issue: Problem is, that paypal actually charges, so the request IS VALID. BUT the checkout process shows up as invalid, so the response is NOT VALID. Paypal support says that they do not know what is different to requests we sent to them (from others of our website) and that the request was done correctly. So we have other websites using same technology and request and no one has a clue what is wrong.

Comment: Would you mind moving this to a comment pls?  It isn't really an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had today some problems with the PayPal post response after customers shopping. Some of them never came and some came late after the actual payment. At the moment it is solved but I think we're debugging problems on the PayPal Server. I guess the best solution is to wait for other constumers with similar problems and PayPal response.